# Multiple TakeProfit Indicator

Tags: pine-script

I wanted to make an indicator which will have 3 take profits. Let's make, tp1 = 1%, tp2 = 5% and tp3 = 10% respectively from the last signal.
Here, I wanted to make tp1 appear only when the price fails to breach tp2 and returns to tp1 again.

Comment: So what is your problem? Take a look on this example https://ru.tradingview.com/script/kHhCik9f-Multiple-profit-exits-example/

Comment: Actually, I want a syntax to trigger a number when it reaches while returning.
For ex, I wanna trigger alert when the price is 10, but it should not be triggered when it reaches 10 from 9. It should trigger when it returns back to 10 after reaching any value like 13 from 9.